# Rails can CarrierWave preserve images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to store some logo images for my records, on Amazon S3.
I would like carrier wave to NOT delete the images when the records are destroyed.

Is there a way to purposely inhibit this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ActiveRecord's `delete` method instead of `destroy`, callbacks won't be fired, and your image will remain.